# Php counter and Substring Concatenation

Tags: php, concatenation

I am working on a car rental system, where the user can add a car into the php script which thereby adds the values into the back end dababase. I have a field called 'ID' which is auto incremented INT field. Everytime I add a car, the value is automatically added as an incremented Integer. Now, how I actually want it to be is different, for example if the name of the car to be added is 'MERCEDES', the ID value should be MER001. If the next car then added is VAUXHALL, the ID value should be VAU002 and so on. I know how to get 'MER' out of mercedes using the substring function in php, but I dont know how to have a loop counter and concatenate it with the extracted substring. I believe for this the ID field in my database table will have to be a VARCHAR but I dont know if a VARCHAR can be auto-incrementing (doesnt make sense). Here's the form to add the car.

## Add a new Car to the database

Fill in the details below to Register

```
  <label> Car Name
  <span class="small">Enter car name</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="CARNAME" id="CARNAME" />

  <label>Fuel Type
  <span class="small">Eg: Petrol</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="FUELTYPE" id="FUELTYPE" />

  <label>Transmission
  <span class="small">Eg: Manuel</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="TRANSMISSION" id="TRANSMISSION" />

  <label>Engine Size
  <span class="small">Eg: 2.4</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="ENGINE_SIZE" id="ENGINE_SIZE" />

  <label>Doors
  <span class="small">Eg: 4</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="DOORS" id="DOORS" />

  <label>Total
  <span class="small">Eg: 40</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="TOTAL" id="TOTAL" />

  <label>Available
  <span class="small">Eg: 40</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="AVAILABLE" id="AVAILABLE" />


  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Car">
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  </form>
```

This form takes you to adding.php which has the following code:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect ("xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
mysql_select_db ("xxxxx");

$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$CARNAME = $_POST['CARNAME'];
$FUELTYPE = $_POST['FUELTYPE'];
$TRANSMISSION = $_POST['TRANSMISSION'];
$ENGINE_SIZE = $_POST['ENGINE_SIZE'];
$DOORS = $_POST['DOORS'];
$TOTAL = $_POST['TOTAL'];
$AVAILABLE = $_POST['AVAILABLE'];
$DATEADDED = $_POST['DATEADDED'];
$test = substr($CARNAME,0,3); //tried to use this test variable and it works to get the substring!

if($TOTAL>=$AVAILABLE)
{     
$query = "insert into car (ID,CARNAME,FUELTYPE,TRANSMISSION,ENGINE_SIZE,DOORS,TOTAL,AVAILABLE,DATEADDED) values ('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[CARNAME]','$_POST[FUELTYPE]','$_POST[TRANSMISSION]','$_POST[ENGINE_SIZE]','$_POST[DOORS]','$_POST[TOTAL]','$_POST[AVAILABLE]',CURDATE())";
$result = mysql_query($query);
header("location: list_logged.php");
}
else
{
echo "<script>alert('The Total number of cars cannot be less than Available number!'); location.href='add.php';</script>"; 
}
mysql_close ($link);

?>
```

Any suggestions as to how I can post something to ID to make it like MER001, MAC002...and so on? Right now it is just set to an auto incrementing value, which is added automatically. I know I'd have to change the field in the database from ID to VARCHAR but I dont know what to do next. I tried searching similar questions on substr and php counter concatenation but found nothing useful.

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you're passing unfiltered, unvalidated user data directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: Hi Charles,
I am aware of that, I will work on it, Thanks :)
Any suggestions on the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time and figured it out. You should really use PDO though. Also your database will look like this:

ID, CARNAME, FUELTYPE, TRANSMISSION, ENGINE_SIZE, DOORS, TOTAL, AVAILABLE, AND DATEADDED (WHICH IS A DATETIME DATA TYPE. THE REST ARE ALL VARCHARS).

One more thing. Instead of using CURDATE() you use NOW() which gives the date and time of insert into the db.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect ("***", "****", "*******");
mysql_select_db ("*****");

$CARNAME = $_POST['CARNAME'];
$FUELTYPE = $_POST['FUELTYPE'];
$TRANSMISSION = $_POST['TRANSMISSION'];
$ENGINE_SIZE = $_POST['ENGINE_SIZE'];
$DOORS = $_POST['DOORS'];
$TOTAL = $_POST['TOTAL'];
$AVAILABLE = $_POST['AVAILABLE'];

    //FUNCTION TO GET LAST ID FROM DB
    function getLastID(){ //Function to get last ID created and return
        $query = "SELECT ID FROM car ORDER BY DATEADDED DESC LIMIT 1;";
        $lastID = mysql_query($query);
        $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($lastID);
        return $results; //returns last id
    }

    //SWITCH CASE TO CREATE PREPENDING CARNAME
    switch ($CARNAME) { //PreString based off of form input
        case 'MERCEDES':
        $preString = 'MER';
            break;
        case 'VAUXHALL':
        $preString = 'VAU';
            break;
        default:
        $preString = 'NONE';
            break;
    }
    //CREATING NEW INDEX
    $newID = getLastID(); // Get Newest ID from the database
    $castNewID = (String) $newID['ID']; //Cast ID to String
    $last3chars = substr($castNewID, -3);  //Get last three characters of ID
    $newIndexNumber = (int) $last3chars + 1; // Cast last3chars to int and add one
    $castToString = str_pad((String) $newIndexNumber, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //Append zeros to string if we haven't reached 100 yet and cast back into a string.
    $newCarID = (String) $preString . (String) $castToString; //Finally create new ID concatenation

    //var_dump($newCarID); //For debugging

    //INSERT INTO DB
    if($TOTAL>=$AVAILABLE)
    {     
        $query = "insert into car (ID,CARNAME,FUELTYPE,TRANSMISSION,ENGINE_SIZE,DOORS,TOTAL,AVAILABLE,DATEADDED) 

                    values ('$newCarID', '$CARNAME', '$FUELTYPE','$TRANSMISSION','$ENGINE_SIZE','$DOORS','$TOTAL','$AVAILABLE',NOW())";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        header("location: list_logged.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('The Total number of cars cannot be less than Available number!'); location.href='add.php';</script>"; 
    }
    mysql_close ($link);


?>
```

Comment: Dont understand this, Thanks for your help though. Any other solutions? I was simply thinking of type-casting the ID into String and then concatenating it with the Substring and then putting that value into the CARID which is a varchar field. I know you have done something similar, but it did not help me a lot :/

Comment: Well that's what's going on with this script. But you don't typecast the $_POST['ID'] because there is no input from the form. You simply pull the last ID number from the database and do some manipulating to generate the next one. The function getLastID pulls the latest ID from the database. The switch statement is based off of the input from the Form (i.e. if it was 'Mercedes' then 'Mer' will be part of the new ID', etc.)

Comment: Next you just store the ID into variable called $newID by using that function, cast the results (which is in an associative array) into a String, get the last 3 characters (which is the most recent 3 digit number), cast it into an Int to add 1 to it, cast it back into a string, then add the prestring from the switch to the castToString and insert into the db. It's extremely simple, have you simply tried this way out yet?

Comment: But I see what your saying, your still using ID and CARID in your database. Using the script I made, the ID is a VARCHAR Primary Key, not an auto_increment. If you would like keep the ID auto incremented and put the new number into CARID I can change it for you